# Notice: Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object in

Tags: php

Me aparecen estos errores justo debajo de la variable result, en el if y despues en el row, y no se como arreglarlo, porque tampoco acabo de entender bien el error. A ver si podrian ayudarme.

Notice: Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\php\checklogin.php on line 24

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\php\checklogin.php:26 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\php\checklogin.php on line 26

```
session_start();
?>

<?php

include('conexion.php');

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'prueba');

if($mysqli->connect_error){

    die('Error en la conexion' . $mysqli->connect_error);

}

$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$passwd = $_POST['passwd'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM 'web_users' WHERE usuario = '$usuario'";

$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {   }

$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

var_dump($row);

if ($passwd == $row['passwd'] && $usuario == $row['usuario']) {

    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
    $_SESSION['start'] = time();
    $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (5 * 60);

    echo "Bienvenido! " . $_SESSION['usuario'];
    echo "<br><br><a href=panel-control.php>Panel de Control</a>";
    header('Location: panel-control.php'); //redirecciona a la pagina del usuario

} else {

    echo "Username o Password estan incorrectos.";
    echo "<br><a href='../index.html'>Volver a Intentarlo</a>";
}

mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

Comment: Lo he hecho y me devuelve false. No me esta trayendo bien los datos del usuario que he registrado anteriormente en la web, pero tampoco se porque no me lo llega a traer si el código creo que está bien

Comment: Pues de ahi el error inicial, no puedes acceder a una propiedad de un objeto que de hecho no lo es, debes regresar sobre tus pasos y evaluar si tu conexión por ejemplo es correcta y funciona

Comment: Es un usuario con varios campos, deberia cogerlo bien. He hecho un `var_dump` de la conexion y me ha devuelto esto:

`object(mysqli)#1 (18) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(0) ["client_info"]=> string(14) "mysqlnd 7.4.16" ["client_version"]=> int(70416) ["connect_errno"]=> int(0) ["connect_error"]=> NULL ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["field_count"]=> int(0) ["host_info"]=> string(20) "localhost via TCP/IP" ["info"]=> NULL ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["server_info"]=> string(21) "5.5.5-10.4.18-MariaDB"`

y algunas cosas mas pero no entran en el comentario

Comment: Pues yo te diría que en tu `SELECT` noto un error pues las comillas que uses en el nombre de la tabla deben ser backticks `` y no comillas simples como le has puesto

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda, ese era el fallo, que hacia referencia a la tabla con las comillas. Ya se ha logueado de forma correcta.

Comment: La cosa es que no me aparece la opción para cerrarla